# sequentially deserialize using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a value object serialized and deserialized using Jackson.

The VO has two fields: x and y. But invoking setY makes sense only when x is set. Is there any way I can make sure that setX is invoked earlier than setY during de-serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it only by implementing custom deserializer for your POJO (VO) class. Let assume that you POJO class looks like this:

```
class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

Now, you can implement deserializer. You can do it in this way:

```
class PointJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Point> {

    @Override
    public Point deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        InnerPoint root = jp.readValueAs(InnerPoint.class);

        Point point = new Point();
        point.setX(root.x);
        point.setY(root.y);

        return point;

    }

    private static class InnerPoint {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }
}
```

After that, you have to tell Jackson to use above deserializer. For example, in this way:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = PointJsonDeserializer.class)
class Point {
     ...
}
```

For me, your `setY` brakes setter method responsibility. You should avoid situation like that where you hide class logic in setter method. Better solution is creating new method for calculations:

```
point.setX(10);
point.setY(11);
point.calculateSomething();
```

Comment: Ziober Thanks for your response! What if setting x should modify the value of x?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you, please, give me more details?

Comment: Ziober: Sorry, that was a typo - I meant: "what if setting 'y' should modify the value of 'x'? In that case, calculateSomething gets invoked inside the setter for 'y' because the code is expected to be tightly coupled.

Comment: It looks like you want to do more than only set 'Y' value. I think, set method should only set value. If you want to recalculate another property in set method, you can add new method for this.