# How to parse JSON element that can be either simple string or an object into Class Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am not able to unmarshall a JSON key which can hold either a string value or an another JSON Object using Jackson Library.

Ex:- Below are the two possible values.

1)

```
"ProviderData": {
    "INVALID": "HEX",
    "#text": "Sample"
}
```

2)

```
"ProviderData": "1C"
```

Could someone please verify and suggest me on this issue.

Comment: Do you have two different java objects to map, or how does the object look like?

Comment: In case there is a `String` - `1C`, what does it mean? Is it `INVALID` or `#text` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom deserialiser and handle these both cases or write two constructors for `ProviderData` `POJO` class and properly use [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) and [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotations. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Response.class));
    }
}

class Response {

    @JsonProperty("ProviderData")
    private ProviderData data;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class ProviderData {

    private static final String INVALID_NAME = "INVALID";
    private static final String TEXT_NAME = "#text";

    @JsonProperty(INVALID_NAME)
    private final String invalid;

    @JsonProperty(TEXT_NAME)
    private final String text;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public ProviderData(String invalid) {
        this(invalid, null);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public ProviderData(@JsonProperty(INVALID_NAME) String invalid, @JsonProperty(TEXT_NAME) String text) {
        this.invalid = invalid;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // getters, toString
}
```

For this `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "ProviderData": {
    "INVALID": "HEX",
    "#text": "Sample"
  }
}
```

Above example prints:

```
Response{data=ProviderData{invalid='HEX', text='Sample'}}
```

And for `String` primitive `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "ProviderData": "1C"
}
```

Above example prints:

```
Response{data=ProviderData{invalid='1C', text='null'}}
```

As you can see, `JSON Object` is mapped properly using `2-arg` constructor and `String` primitive is mapped using `1-arg` constructor and we assume that this value means `invalid` key from `JSON Object` example.

See also:

1. [Custom JSON Deserialization with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson).
2. [sequentially deserialize using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151396/sequentially-deserialize-using-jackson).
3. [Deserialize strings and objects using jackson annotations in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151396/sequentially-deserialize-using-jackson).

Comment: @AnkammaRao, I'm glad it works. Since you are new user, please, take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

you could deserialize to `JsonNode` and then extract the contents individually, or deserialize to an `Object` and use `instanceof` to determine if it's a `Map` or another type, or use a [custom deserializer](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-custom-deserializer) to unpack the data into a custom object that handles both cases.